# Re-arranging lines in a file

Tags: php, arrays, file, input, io

I'm trying to read data from a text file and assign it to arrays. How could I read exactly 3 lines at a time, and then assign the first line to array $a, second line to array $b, third line to array $c? and then read exactly 3 more lines, etc.

Comment: Use fgets -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$lines    = file('some_file.txt');
$numLines = count($lines);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numLines; $i += 3) {
    $a[] = $lines[$i];
    $b[] = $lines[$i + 1];
    $c[] = $lines[$i + 2];
}
```

Note that you'll want to do some out-of-bounds index error checking, as well.  I leave that as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: It'd be better to stream the data form the file using `fgets` rather than buffering it...

Comment: @WillVousden: I suppose it depends on the average size of the file that's being read as to whether or not streaming would make any discernible difference, but that information wasn't provided.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fseek`, or `file_get_contents` with maxlen parameter. But to read exactly 3 lines, I don't actually know, unless you know how long are these lines.

function `file` reads all lines into an array.

Edit two:
Could read the file byte by byte (although a bad idea from my point of view) and stop after you encounter each `\n` or `PHP_EOL` and use a counter or whatever to manage how it is used.

Edit one:

I just got this idea: you could create a custom stream wrapper, and handle your reading the lines 3 by 3 with it. It is a great tool for files, check http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php , and control it with through context or variables, or what ever.

I guess you still will have to find an algorithm for this. I didn't tried this yet, but let us know if you handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The example for `fgets` should give you some ideas:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php#refsect1-function.fgets-examples

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this for example:

```
$lines = file('filename');
$chunks_array = array_chunk($lines, 3)); - this create array of arrays with 3 lines each

foreach ($chunks_array as $chunks)
{
    $a[] = $chunks[0];
    $b[] = $chunks[1];
    $c[] = $chunks[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once I had a similar problem. I solve like this (in pseudocode).

```
counter = 1;

while reading
switch counter
case 1: store in the first array then break;
case 2: store in the second array then break;
case 3: store in the third array, counter = 0, then break;

counter++;

end-while
```